# I'm having an issue with installing an addon

Tags: add-on

So when I try to install an addon, the addon will not appear or show up when I try to type it's exact name in the search bar. I've seen posts but none of them work for some reason. I've tried manually putting it in the addons folder, changed versions, trying extracted folders, too many attempts, but it won't work.

Addon I used is this: https://github.com/Amrsatrio/BlenderUmap/releases/tag/v0.4.3.

It could maybe be because of way the file is maybe? I'm not too sure. Any advice would be really helpful, like if the version im using is not accurate, the version i need, anything please, i will try to respond back to you if you have a solution

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a Blender addon! Read the 'Usage' section [here](https://github.com/Amrsatrio/BlenderUmap/blob/v0.4.3/README.md) !

Comment: Yes, but I do not know python so i dont know how else to import it

Comment: I was just pointing out that it isn't actually a blender addon so you won't be able to install it as one!

Comment: Well it has to be something cause i have seen others with this on blender

Comment: Since there haven't been any comments from anyone else here, it's possible that no-one here has ever heard of or used it. If you've seen others using it with Blender I suggest you ask them. (This is a Q&A site for using Blender and its built-in addons not for third-party programs.)